# How to use cocoa static libraries correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, unity-game-engine

i am currently trying to build a plugin for unity. where i invoke the built in camera on iOS device, using cocoa static library. So I've managed to build a bridge that can do a couple of things. i can recall an int and a string and a method. but in my method parts I'm having problems because i can't seem to do anything inside them.

Here is an example of loading a button, but the complier gives me an error 
= use of undeclared identifier view

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

here is another example where it has an issue with self.view 
= Member reference type 'struct objc_class

```
 UIView *myBox  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 35, 10, 10)];
    myBox.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myBox];
```

so i guess my question is how do i make things happen without using self? or is that the only way i can make things draw.

as you can see I'm pretty confused. if anyone can share some light on the matter that would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use cocoa. It's OS X only. Did you mean to use cocoa-touch?

Comment: no. its definitely a "cocoa static library". this is the tutorial start where you use c++ to speak to objective-c -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zl7VCfLEKvw&list=PLf8PfKIJPGkjhMgylU87G5A0JLMSy_8ad&index=3

Comment: @JoeBlow, you didn't get me right there. unity any cocoa are two pairs of shoes; the 'ios' and 'cocoa' tags in the same question is the problem here.

Comment: purely FYI @LukeCarelsen just so you know or anyone googling here.  very fortunately it's now quite easy to use the raw camera in Unity (it was always a pain in the past) http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/909967/getting-a-web-cam-to-play-on-ui-texture-image.html  I realize you are probably making a plugin for the exercise of it, just a pointer for anyone who googles here.  (It often happens with Unity people start making a whole plugin to do something, not realising it's built-in!)

Comment: Thanks @JoeBlow - we are actually trying to build it for a game I'm working on. And i actually  have explored that avenue, but maybe i should revisit it your solution again. but the actual point of all of this is that if i can get this right, one step at a time. then eventually i could call all native functions which could really come in handy when making content with unity.